# Is this spam and should it be flagged as such?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, flagging, spam

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18737/my-php-ajax-bridge-to-jquery-library

I include the conversation that started all of this as well:

[Chat Conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/conversation/is-this-spam)

It really shows my arguments for it.

I want to hear both sides of the argument here.

*For more information on [Spam flags and Offensive flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only problem with this question is that it doesn't [include the code within the question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/can-i-put-my-code-on-a-third-party-site-and-link-to-the-site-in-my-question)

If spam is "Hey, take a look at my code!", then Code Review is *meant* for spam.

For me, a **real** spam question would contain less text, and being a lot more unclear. Spam questions would also probably link to an available product instead of some code.

Sure there's some bragging about the code. For this specific question, the line "I can assure this is the best jQuery <=> PHP bridge library there is for PHP 5.3 at the moment." could instead be rephrased to "I believe this is the best (...)".

**"Bragging" about code that you have written is not spam.**

Even when you're quite sure that your code is really neat, most of us are just human - which means that we can have some lack of self-confidence, in which case it is good to know if others agree with you or not.

Answer (score 6):

It's not quite spam.  However, it doesn't appear to be genuinely seeking review, so I chose "Unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 3):

Calling it spam is harsh, I just want it closed since it sits in my JavaScript queue and there is nothing I can do with this 'question'. ( So, I did not flag it as spam ).