# Reviewing software, not only code

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

I'm looking for some people/community who are doing each others' software reviews, but not only code. Actually code is the least important. I would like somebody look at my software as a whole and tell me his opinion about future development. Somebody who can look at my website (which shows my software) and tell me what he doesn't like.

Of course I can do the same for others. Actually, such online community works for writers...

Comment: Migrated to meta, this is not a great place for this question, but it is better than the main site.

Comment: Note: pre-migration this post was tagged [css] - is "not only code" referring to that?

Comment: I was clueless how to tag it, and because my software is CSS preprocessor I choose CSS...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I understand your concern, but Code Review is unfortunately not the place that you are looking for.

I would recommend asking among your friends, on Twitter/Facebook, or on Reddit.

Or you could [propose a new Stack Exchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) for "Software Reviews". Or take a look at the existing related proposals:

- [Design Review](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67793/design-review)
- [Website Review](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/68203/website-review)
- [Software Quality Assurance and Testing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2241/software-quality-assurance-testing)

Out of these, Website Review sounds like what you are primarily looking for. So go ahead and contribute to the proposal. Follow the proposal and ask example questions, and recruit additional followers, to help it reach the next phase!

Although be aware that as it currently seems, it is unlikely that there will be such a Stack Exchange site. This is because Stack Exchange sites does not like to be dependent on third party links, something which seems unavoidable for this kind of site. On Code Review we work around this problem by forcing the code to be reviewed to be [inside the question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/can-i-put-my-code-on-a-third-party-site-and-link-to-the-site-in-my-question).

On Code Review, it's the code that is in focus. A [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) can sometimes be a part of a review, or added as a comment (but are not the primary focus). But to get such reviews/comments here, you need to post an on-topic question, which needs to include code.

Comment: As a moderator on SQA, I do not believe a general "review my software" would be welcome. However, you could probably achieve the same results if you took the "teach to fish" approach. You could probably describe a bit about the app and what your goal is (better usability? better reliability?) and then ask "how would I test such an app for _____?" You could also consider the existing "User Experience" Stack Exchange, they might be able to help in that regard.

Answer (score 5):

Reviewing *software as a whole* is probably something you'd want done professionally, by people you're paying to dig into your code and issue recommendations. Reviewing a whole project is tedious, it takes a lot of time and effort.

On Code Review we review *code*, but our definition of *code* sure includes scripts ([javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [php](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php)), but [html](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html) and [css](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css) are certainly reviewable, too (hence, we have tags for them!).

You have found what I firmly believe is the best place on the Internet to get your project reviewed, to get a number of eyes and new perspectives on what you've written.

However people on Code Review are *volunteers*, people that *enjoy* reviewing other people's code - reviewers do this for <s>free</s> *the imaginary Internet points*, and asking them to spend a day or two on your code to produce a thorough review, is a bit of a stretch. Not to mention the 30K character limit [thankfully] imposed by the StackExchange software.

---

The solution is to break your project down into *parts*, or *themes*, that suit a particular specific tag or group of tags (see [our tags](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags)), and to ask reviewers to review what you're posting (make sure you embed the relevant code/script/markup in the question).

For example, your web application might be following a MVC architecture - you could post a model, a view and a controller together in one post and ask for that to be reviewed.

The controller might have a dependency on a service that performs CRUD operations - that service could be the subject of another post.

The view might have a dependency on a CSS style sheet - you could post the markup and the CSS and ask for that to be peer reviewed.

The idea is to keep your posts digestible, so that when the *volunteers* scanning the site for [zombies](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1511/23788) (unanswered questions) stumble upon your post, they *want* to take the time to write down their thoughts in an answer.

---

I don't agree with @Simon's idea (yes, that's my downvote!) to use another site for this. CR is proven, it's been around - *and yet it's still in beta*. Diluting the idea of a peer review into multiple sites isn't going to help anything. I wouldn't want to review a whole entire code base at once, not for free.

Comment: As I understand it, the OP is looking for a different kind of review, with questions such as: "Is this monster in this RPG game good for players?", "Does this website and software provide a good user experience?". Such questions does not fit into Code Review. And btw, I didn't say that I was very fond of the idea of a "Software Review" site myself, but I'm saying that if that is what you are looking for, then Area51 is the way to go.

Comment: Precisely Simon. I'm looking for such kind of review. Area51 is looking promising. Thanks!