# Is Code Review an appropriate place to get feedback on a library?

Tags: discussion, scope

Most of the posts I see on Code Review involve short code sniplets.

Is it appropriate to elicit feedback on an entire (albeit small) library?

Specific example: I've quietly developed [this](https://bitbucket.org/cowwoc/preconditions/) over the past year. The library's goal is to improving code readability of other Java libraries. I'd like to get developers' opinions on what it's missing, and whether this kind of library is of any interest to anyone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure.  Your library looks small enough to make a good Code Review question.  Post your question with the [library](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library) tag and please [ensure that all code to be reviewed is embedded in the post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1309/120114).

I recommend embedding just `Preconditions.java`, maybe two other classes, and an example to illustrate the usage directly in the question.  Provide a link to Bitbucket in case reviewers want to look at the rest of the library.

Comment: Done: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/69355/30683. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry about the unclear wording — we do need the code that is central to the question to be embedded directly in the question, not just linked.

Comment: Updated question. Thanks for the head's up.