# Can I ask for a Review over a GitHub project - if I'm looking for review over the overall architecture?

Tags: discussion, questions

Very Related Question : [Can I put my code on a third party site and link to the site in my question?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1308/56262)

---

I plan on moving my project to GitHub, and I was wondering if I would be able to ask for a Code Review on the overall architecture of the project when I am finished.

Following the information in the related question above, **I could explain and post code samples on the code relevant to explain the overall design** - but if I post the entire code of each piece it would probably be "too much".

But then, if I were to do that, I am not posting a complete, running sample of code - (*unless you were to visit the GitHub*), and I know we don't really like external links.

Can I ask for a review over my overall project if I've provided pieces of code relevant to the overall design, but to see *all* the code you'd have to go to a third-party site (Github, etc.)?

<sub>Everything seems to point to the answer being "no", which is fine - I just thought I'd ask to be sure.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for asking - please let me know if the linked duplicate answers your question :-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes, I think it does - I wasn't following a specific design pattern but it still applies I would think.